# In a Terraform project, how can I specify a version of the current configuration?

Tags: terraform, semantic-versioning

I want to specify a `version` attribute that I can use to set the version of the current configuration.

I appreciate if you can provide the link of the documentation for it.

Note: I don't mean the `required_version` attribute.

In the terraform block, I specified a version attribute, but it didn't work.

```
terraform {
  version = "1.0.0"
  ...
}
```

The error:
$ terraform init
There are some problems with the configuration, described below.

The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.

```
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 2, in terraform:
│    2:   version = "1.0.0"
│ 
│ An argument named "version" is not expected here.
╵
```

Comment: "I specified a version attribute, but it didn't work." - how exactly did you do that? What is your TF code? What errors did you get?

Comment: I just edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Terraform has no concept of a configuration having a version number.

Packages containing shared modules (published in a module registry) can have versions, but that's the version of the entry in the registry index and not something inherent to the module itself.

If you want to treat your own configurations as versioned then you'll need to invent your own way to represent that. I'm not sure what to suggest because it isn't clear from your question what exactly your goal is with choosing a version number, but one possible answer would be to place the version number in a local value:

```
locals {
  version = "1.0.0"
}
```

You can then refer to this value elsewhere in the same module using the expression `local.version`.